# is there a whitelist-like inverse of attr_readonly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, activerecord

attr_protected lets you mark specific columns as protected, vs. attr_accessible which lets you mark all except a given set as protected. attr_readonly lets you mark specific columns as readonly. Is there an inverse that lets you mark all columns except for a given set as readonly?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're after `attr_accessible`, which specifies the columns which are "mass-assignable" (as in, they can be passed into `create` and `update_attributes`). In effect this would mean they are protected from being written to.

To set this attribute:

```
@user.admin = true
@user.save
```

Comment: Nope, I'm looking for a way to say "this model has some important stuff in it, and I want it to be the default for all columns that it's impossible to screw up my controller code, or mess around in the console in a way that would overwrite them."

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but I've found this works:

```
after_initialize do
  mutable_attributes = ["status", "updated_at"]
  self.class.attr_readonly *(self.attributes.keys - mutable_attributes)
end
```